# I am creating an inventory system in Python for my employer, should I store inventory information in an SQLite database?

Tags: python, sqlite, class, inventory-management

I have begun creating an inventory system in Python for my employer. I have the frontend GUI mostly complete and have questions about the backend.

How should I store the information?

The program will be located in a dropbox folder that can be accessed by multiple people at once. Should I use an SQLite database, and upon executing functions such as "add stock", open a connection, execute the change, and close the connection? Will this allow multiple users to have the inventory open at once? Are there better ways to handle this?

There won't be a lot of inventory items. Would it be better to use python objects and object methods to store and manipulate the information?

Comment: If you're trying to do database-like operations, you should probably use a database. Otherwise, how do you envision using python objects to track inventory changes?

Comment: I thought maybe that creating objects with attributes such as "count", "price", etc would work if there were a way to keep the attribute changes over closing and re-opening of the application.

Comment: There are ways, such as a `.csv` or `pickle` file that you can use to persist data or python objects between sessions, but it's really down to your use case

Comment: Have you read the warnings about sqlite and multiple concurrent accesses?

Comment: I have not, I just looked and it seems it won't be a problem because the likelihood of more than one person on at a time is small (although existent). And even if there is more than one person, their updates will be minor, and, according to the warning, will take milliseconds to complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manipulate an sqlite database pretty easily with Python.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

```
import sqlite3 as sql

class SQLManiuplator:
  def __init__(self, fp=None):
    path = fp
    if not fp:
      path = "example.db"
    self.path = path

  def add_item_to_inventorytable(self, item):
    with sql.connect(self.path) as conn: # close automatically
        c = conn.cursor()
        # Use '?' substitution to sanitize inputs per sqlite3 docs
        c.execute('''
        INSERT INTO inventory VALUES (?)''', item)
        c.commit()

  # More CRUD functions
```

You can built a pretty CRUD api with this pattern and map the operations to your GUI. From a design standpoint, it then falls to you to decide what operations you are willing to expose to your users. For example I don't suppose you will want to make `CREATE TABLE` available to users so I didn't include that. (But this means you would have to manually create tables and define what columns exist in them.)

You already said that this would be a pretty lightweight inventory system, but it should go without saying that at enterprise scale this solution is a loser.

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful. If you don't mind, I have another question for you, with the c.execute method, is there a way to take in a variable amount of arguments? I was planning on having multiple tables, and some have a different number of columns. I know that in javascript you can use the "arguments" object to retrieve and iterate through a variable number of arguments. I would like to avoid creating several functions for each table if possible.

Comment: @BlorbieRandy check out the python `splat` operator. Learning about `decorators` in python taught me a lot about `splat`

Comment: You're welcome! If the response helped resolve your issue you can mark it up or mark it answered @BlorbieRandy